# Does this women's hair style have a name?

Tags: hair

Could someone please tell me if there's a name for this women's hairdo?

The pictures are from "Spy Game" and "Summer Heights High"

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean how her hair is kind of in a ponytail?

Answer (score 0):

It is called a **pixie ponytail** or **mini ponytail**.

See Cosmopolitan's [JoJo Siwa just chopped off her iconic ponytail and got a pixie cut](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/beauty-hair/celebrity-hair-makeup/a39672412/jojo-siwa-pixie-cut/)

Comment: Is it a pony tail?
I had something like this in mind.... 
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/507217976793158336/

Comment: Well, it has to be gripped with *something*.